# Akka actor path protocols

Tags: akka

In Akka are actor paths ever prefixed by anything other than `akka://`? What if the actor is remote? Any variations of this protocol, and if so, what are they and when are they used by the actor system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akka uses an [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) to locate actors in the actor system and by definition all URI require to have a scheme, thus `akka://` is the scheme of URI used by akka.

Remoting does use a different scheme `akka.<protocol>`, it's `akka.tcp` if tcp protocol is used. See the official [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/remoting.html#looking-up-remote-actors)